# how to give blinking effects in jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, queue

i want this type of animation in my code but dont know how to perform. I have 5 logo images in which when click any one of them then following animation should take place the clicked logo:

The 1st one should get shrink on click and then zoom and then again shrink and then get disappear. (*disappearence should be only by using `opacity:0`) and animation for the other logos:
In between this animation all the other logos have the same animation defined above in random order and get disappear so fast that user get a blinking effect in logo disappearence. Then the container div should get hidden.

All the code I have tried so far is given below. This code is achieving first part which is on click it get shrink and then zoom and then get shrink again and disappear.

some one has told me to use queue in chaining animation but how should i use it here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

          $(".l1").click(function(){
                      $(".l1").animate({
                      height:'90px', 
                      width:'90px', 
                      opacity:'0.5',
                      queue:false,
                      duration:1000
                      },"easeInOutSine")
                             .animate({
                              height:'128px', 
                              width:'128px', 
                              opacity:'0.6',
                              queue: true,
                              duration: 1000,
                              },"easeInOutSine",function() { })
                              .animate({
                              height:'50px', 
                              width:'50px', 
                              opacity:'0',
                              queue: true,
                              duration: 1000,
                              },"easeInOutSine",function() {

                              });

                      });
});

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
      <td><img src="img/coke.png"   class="l1"/></td>
      <td><img src="img/coke.png"   class="l2"/></td>
      <td><img src="img/coke.png"   class="l3"/></td>
      <td><img src="img/coke.png"   class="l4"/></td>
      <td><img src="img/coke.png"   class="l5"/></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey hii user, 
             Use fadeIn() and fadeOut() in jquery, here is the code,
`$(this).fadeOut().next().delay(500).fadeIn();`

Comment: can you provide me a working demo of this code or tell me whether should i apply this

Comment: @user2750762 checkout my answer with a working demo

Comment: buddy try your code replace $('.l1')

 by $('.li')

Comment: i didn't understand . l1 is the class name and li is the tag  here i am not using list

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI Highlight Effect is what you need to achieve it easily.

```
$("l1").click(function () {
      //$(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000); //If you need to play with time
      $( this ).toggle( "highlight" );
});
```

The documentation and demo can be found here.
http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/

[Here is a example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NsFgQ/)

Comment: this is the same effect that i want but zooming part is not included can u plz tell me how should i do this for all logo